# pubnub presence detection of all the channels together without subscribing to any of them

Tags: pubnub

Using pubnub i know that its possible to find out the presence of another person subscribed on the same channel. My question is that, if I have a web app running, and I use pubnub in my app, is it possible for me on the server to maintain presence information of each user by using pubnub api's and without having to subscribe to any channel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For full details, see the knowledge base article, [Can PubNub call my server via Webhooks when presence events occur?](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/1128/can-pubnub-call-my-server-via-webhooks-when-presence-events-occur)

Comment: Thanks. That helped. :)