# pubnub channels get deleted after some time

Tags: android, chat, pubnub

I am integrating pubnub chat application with my android app, where I am creating a channel for two users `ramesh` and `paul` with channel name `ramesh_paul`, subscribing two users. I am not pushing any messages to that channel but after 15 minutes the channel is getting deleted.

Comment: Actually i created channel ramesh_paul and subscribed ramesh and paul, also ramesh as a publisher. Immidiately if i call wherenow for ramesh i am getting ramesh_paul in the channels list. After 15 if i call wherenow i am not getting ramesh_paul channel name

Comment: So it sounds like you are all good now, right?

Comment: yes, it works now. Thank you @CraigConover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub Channel Lifecycle

Channels are not necessarily created nor destroyed - at least not from the developer's point of view. They are either *active* or *inactive*.

**ACTIVE** means that someone is subscribed and **INACTIVE** means no one is currently subscribed. If someone subscribes to the channel, it will be active again. This active/inactive is all about occupancy or the lack there of on a channel which is what [PubNub Presence](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/categories/presence) is all about.

- If you do not publish to that channel in 15 minutes, or in 15 days or ever, but someone is subscribed to the channel, then it is active.
- If you publish to the channel but no one is subscribed to it, then it is inactive but the publish still goes through to PubNub without error.
- If you have Storage & Playback enabled, then PubNub will persist the message for that channel.

So *channel gets deleted* is not something that is happening. Check out the [PubNub Knowledge Base](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/) for more details about [channels](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/categories/channels) and [channel groups](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/categories/channel-groups).

Above when I speak of *active* and *inactive* channels, I am hinting at a feature called Presence Webhooks. Refer to [this StackOverflow thread for full details about PubNub Presence Webhooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853515/pubnub-presence-detection-of-all-the-channels-together-without-subscribing-to-an).